# How could I rename an item in a simple array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I work on an Angular project and I built an array.
Now I'd like to rename one of the items of the array. I found the way to rename the keys of an array but I still don't know how to do to apply this to its values.

Here is my array below.
I'd like to change 'valueC' by 'valueZ'.

```
myArray = ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC']
```

I tried the following code :

```
    for (const k in this.myArray) {
        if (k == "valueC") {
            this.myArray[k] = "valueZ";
        }
```

But it does not work.

Could you help me ?
Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That `if` should be `if (this.myArray[k] == "valueC")`

Answer (score 1):

Below are two possible methods!

```js
const myArray = ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC']

//rename - if index known
myArray[2] = 'valueZ';
console.log('if index known', myArray);

//rename - if index not known
const foundIndex = myArray.findIndex(x => x === 'valueC');
if (foundIndex > -1) {
  myArray[2] = 'valueZ';
}
console.log('if index not known', myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The thing is that I'm not supposed to know the position of the value in my array. How could it be possible to do without use the index of the item ?

Comment: @Julien my second solution will find the position for you and then update the value!

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you, that works perfectly well !

Comment: But will only replace one occurrence, not two or more. Also, the second solution still replaces the value at index 2 (hardcoded)

Comment: @Julien Do you have more than one occourence to replace?

Comment: In my project I just have one occurence, so it works well in this case !

Answer (score 1):

Your code just needs a minor correction:

```
 if (this.myArray[k] == "valueC")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the index, easy with a forEach

```js
this.myArray.forEach((k, index) => {
   if (k == "valueC") {
     this.myArray[index] = "valueZ";
   }
})
```

My prefered way :
Though, be sure to have the value "valueC" inside the array
otherwise indexOf will return a -1, provoquing an error

```js
// without index control
this.myArray[this.myArray.indexOf("valueC")] = "valueZ";

// with index control
const index = this.myArray.indexOf("valueC")
if (index >= 0) {
  this.myArray[index] = "valueZ";
}
```

Also note this for future usage :)

- for (const k **in** array) : in that case k is the index of elements in array
- for (const k **of** array) : in that case k is the value of elements in array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const myArray = ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC'];
for (const k in myArray) {
  if (myArray[k] == "valueC") {
    myArray[k] = "valueZ";
  }
} 
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of all the other solutions here, another approach, and one I believe is better in that it gets you in the mindset of immutability, is to return a new object instead of modifying the current one.

Ex:

```
this.myArray = this.myArray.map(x => {
    if(x !== 'valueC')
        return x;

    return 'valueZ';
});
```

So map here will return a new array object for us, in this case a string array given your current array is a string array. Another pattern in use here is only checking for the negative case. Instead of having if/else or a chain of them, we know that for all case that aren't 'valueC' we retain their original value and only valueC's value needs to change to valueZ